# How do I fix build error about fPIC?

Tags: source, build

I recently built Monero from master on Manjaro, and there were no issues.  I then built the same commit on an Ubuntu computer and received an error about `fPIC`.

Like ... `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Note that the Ubuntu dependencies had previously been installed via `apt` package manager.  Similarly, the Manjaro dependencies had been installed via `pacman` package manager.  Also, Ubuntu (Lubuntu) is actually 16.04.3 LTS, and Manjaro is 17.1.5.

Also note: I successfully built by editing `CMakeLists.txt` and commenting out `set(PIC_FLAG "-fPIC")` and `add_linker_flag_if_supported(-pie LD_SECURITY_FLAGS)` (not 100% sure the second one was needed).  I'd rather just recompile with `fPIC`, but I don't quite understand what that entails.

Side question: what is it about Manjaro that prevented this `fPIC` issue?

Real question: how do I go about fixing my dependencies to deal with `fPIC`?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3173#issuecomment-360079653) help?

Comment: Sort of, yeah.  Thank you.  I'll post how I solved the problem for myself, though I'm curious about other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem being experienced has to do with how the compiler uses libraries.

As noted in the github link provided by Florian, one solution to this problem is simply to uninstall `libgtest-dev`.  This actually didn't work the first time I tried to `make`.  Once I did `make clean` first, it worked as intended.

Another solution is so comment out the lines of `CMakeLists.txt` that require `-fPIC`. Those were noted in the question.

This answer does not address whether compiling `libgtest-dev` with `-fPIC` would also solve the problem, if so, how to do that.

Comment: It would. And you'd get the source .deb, twiddle the CFLAGS, and PR that to the libgtest-dev maintainer.

Answer (score 3):

I did this to recompile libgtest-dev with -fPIC and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
cd /usr/src/gtest/
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC"
sudo make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```