# Building Monero Fails but works?

Tags: monerod, linux, build, building

I am building Monero from source on Ubunto 16.04 LTS.

Eventually, it gets to 98% but then gives an error. However, I am still able to run monerod. Can anyone elaborate as to what has happened?

(I have tried building on Ubunto 14.04 and 17.04 with failures at around 42% many times. This is the further I have got)

> [ 98%] Linking CXX executable unit_tests /usr/bin/ld:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-al
>   l.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata' can not be used when
>   making a
>   shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a: error
>   adding symbols
>   : Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/build.make:1205: recipe for
>   target 't
>   ests/unit_tests/unit_tests' failed make[3]: ***
>   [tests/unit_tests/unit_tests] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/spencer/monero/build/release' CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4425: recipe
>   for target 'tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_t
>
>   ests.dir/all' failed make[2]:** 
>   [tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]:
>   Leaving directory '/home/spencer/monero/build/release' Makefile:138:
>   recipe for target 'all' failed make[1]:  **[all] Error 2 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory '/home/spencer/monero/build/release' Makefile:64:
>   recipe for target 'release-all' failed make: *** [release-all] Error 2

However, I can run monerod:

> root@aleph3:~/monero/build/release/bin# ./monerod 2018-06-26
>   13:14:45.057     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/main. 
>   cpp:279 Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.2.0-release) 2018-06-26
>   13:14:45.058     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/proto 
>   col.h:53        Initializing cryptonote protocol... 2018-06-26
>   13:14:45.058     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/proto 
>   col.h:58        Cryptonote protocol initialized OK 2018-06-26
>   13:14:45.058     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h 
>   :63     Initializing p2p server... 2018-06-26 13:14:50.939
>   7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h
>   :68     p2p server initialized OK 2018-06-26 13:14:50.939
>   7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h
>   :63     Initializing core RPC server... 2018-06-26 13:14:50.939
>   7f1c80523780        INFO    global  contrib/epee/inc
>   lude/net/http_server_impl_base.h:76     Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
>   2018-06-26 13:14:50.939     7f1c80523780        INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/rpc.h
>   :69     core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081 2018-06-26
>   13:14:50.939     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/core. 
>   h:86    Initializing core... 2018-06-26 13:14:50.940     7f1c80523780 
>   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_c
>   ore/cryptonote_core.cpp:427     Loading blockchain from folder
>   /home/spencer/.bi
>   tmonero/lmdb ... 2018-06-26 13:14:50.940     7f1c80523780        WARN 
>   blockchain.db.lmdb     s
>   rc/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75    Error attempting to retrieve a
>   hard fork
>   version at height 0 from the db: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data
>   pair found 2018-06-26 13:14:51.014     7f1c80523780        INFO
>   global  src/cryptonote_c
>   ore/cryptonote_core.cpp:526     Loading checkpoints 2018-06-26
>   13:14:51.444     7f1c80523780        INFO    global  src/daemon/core. 
>   h:92    Core initialized OK 2018-06-26 13:14:51.444     7f1c80523780
>   INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h
>   :74     Starting core RPC server... 2018-06-26 13:14:51.444 [SRV_MAIN]
>   INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:79    c
>   ore RPC server started ok 2018-06-26 13:14:51.448 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO
>   global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78    S
>   tarting p2p net loop... 2018-06-26 13:14:52.449 [P2P2]  INFO    global
>   src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_c
>   ore.cpp:1354
>   ********************************************************************** The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a
>   long time
>   to complete.
>
> You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log
>   
>   s>" command, where  is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very
>   verbose), or custom category
>   based levels (eg, *:WARNING).
>
> Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands. Use
>   "help " to see a command's documentation.
>
> ---
>
> 2018-06-26 13:15:04.364 [P2P1]  INFO    global 
>   src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptono
>   te_protocol_handler.inl:310     [51.15.179.106:18080 OUT] Sync data
>   returned a n
>   ew top block candidate: 1 -> 1584467 [Your node is 1584466 blocks
>   (1499 days) be
>   hind] SYNCHRONIZATION started ...

Comment: Could you please provide the environment you are trying to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that `make` will build a whole bunch of stuff (i.e., `monerod`, `monero-wallet-cli`, `monero-wallet-gui`, `monero-blockchain-import`, etc., along with all the files it compiles as precursors to those binaries). At the end of the build process, it builds tests.  Your error comes at the stage of the build process where all the main binaries have already successfully been compiled, and it's the building of the tests that has failed.

Your error reflects that you have `libgtest` on your system, but it wasn't compiled with the `-fPIC` flag.  You can either recompile with `-fPIC`, or [see this SE question/answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7604/how-do-i-fix-build-error-about-fpic) for other possible solutions (e.g., uninstall `libgtest`).