# Compiling from source on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

The problem when compiling (by the readme.md guide):

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a
>   shared object; recompile with -fPIC

How do you actually compile with -fPIC? I tried the following:

> export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC"
>   export CXXFLAGS='-O -fPIC'

Comment: See https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7604/how-do-i-fix-build-error-about-fpic